# Node server file handling throws Unexpected end of multipart data

Tags: node.js, multer, busboy

I am streaming jpg file to a node server.But the issue is sometimes it works and some times it fails with the folowing  error and crashes my server

```
 events.js:183
066466+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-06-19T00:45:07.066468+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-06-19T00:45:07.066470+00:00 app[web.1]: 
066472+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unexpected end of multipart data
2018-06-19T00:45:07.066474+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
/app/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:62:28
```

Here is my code to handle the file

```
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {

    console.log("Uploading: " + (filename)); 
    fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/'+ filename);

    file.on('data', function(chunk) {
       fstream.write(chunk);
     });

    file.on('end', function() {
      fstream.end();
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished sucessfully');
     });
    file.on('error',function(err){
      console.log('fstream error' + err);
      file.unpipe();
    });
   });
```

Can somebody please help what could be the issue here?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ok answering my own question.I was not handling error event correctly.Here is the working code.

```
  var fstream;

  req.pipe(req.busboy);

  req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {

      console.log("Uploading: " + (filename)); 
      fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/'+ filename);

      file.on('data', function(chunk) {
         fstream.write(chunk);
       });
       file.on('error',function(err){
        console.log('fstream error ' + err);

      });
      file.on('end', function() {
        fstream.end();
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished sucessfully');
       });


  });

  req.busboy.on('error',function(err){
    console.log('req.busboy error' + err);

  });
```

Comment: so what did u do with the error . I am getting the error but cannot find a way to resolve this